# Formal logic and functions (I am struggling with writing my proof)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I wish to show that $f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)=\bigcup_af(X_a)$

My attempt:
$$y\in f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)\implies\exists x\in\bigcup_aX_a:y\in f(\{x\})$$
which I didn't like, so I re-wrote it as:
$$\forall y\in f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)\exists x\in\bigcup_aX_a:y\in f(\{x\})$$

I have to introduce an $x$, I need to put an exists somewhere (unlike proving De Morgan's laws, where you can just say $x\in$left hand side $\implies\in$RHS and then the other way)

Now I can write the "if $x$ is in the union of some sets it is in at least one of them" nicely as:

$$\forall x\in\bigcup_aX_a\exists b:x\in X_b$$ - given an $x$ I can get a $b$.

How do I use this above?

$$\forall y\in f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)\exists x\exists b:x\in X_b\implies y\in f(\{x\})$$

I am saying for all y there exists an x (based on that y) there exists a b based on that x and y with $x\in X_b$.... surely I could also say "there exists a b where there exists an x such that x in $X_b$ implies...."

I will want to go to:

$\forall y\in f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)\exists b:y\in f(X_b)$ which makes me want to swap round the order of exists.

Then from this we go (not sure how to write it with equal rigor) that y would be in the union of $f(X_a)$ over a.

Completing the proof

### My first attempt:

$y\in f\left(\bigcup_aX_a\right)\implies f^{-1}(\{y\})\subset \bigcup_aX_a$ so $\exists x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ with $x\in\bigcup_aX_a$ which doesn't feel as concrete as I'd like.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA have I made a mistake? I intentionally wrote $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ it is the set that contains $x$ if the function maps x to y. For an infinite set $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ you'd have $f^{-1}(4)=f^{-1}(\{4\})=\{-2,2\}$, I used the set notation to make this more explicit. I never state that the function is surjective or injective because it might be neither.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a real answer, but a *long* comment to jdc's answer.

To be **totally** "formal" is an hard task, due to the huge amont of defined symbols used in set language [see as example : Yuri Manin, [A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461424798) (2010), Chapter 1.3 : **Beginenrs' Course in Translation**, page 9-on].

Let us try with :

> $∃x \in \bigcup_a X_a (f(x)=y)$.

In order to simplify it, abbreviate the formula $(f(x)=y)$ as $\varphi(x,y)$; thus, we have (more "formally") :

$(\exists x) (x \in \bigcup_a X_a \land \varphi(x,y))$.

Now, if we have the simpler case of $X_1 \cup X_2$, our formula will be :

> $(\exists x) [(x \in (X_1 \cup X_2)) \land \varphi(x,y)]$.

This is "quite" first-order logic ...

The condition $x \in (X_1 \cup X_2)$, by definition of *union* of sets, is equivalent to:

$(x \in X_1) \lor (x \in X_2)$.

Now, with the "$\bigcup$-case", we are not allowed to write a "potentially" infinite disjunction; thus, we have to use $\exists$.

We have that $x \in \bigcup_a X_a$ is equivalent to :

$(\exists a) [(a \in A) \land (x \in X_a)]$,

where $A$ is the (left implicit) index-set.

We try now to "assemble" all together :

> > $(\exists x) ( \quad (\exists a) [(a \in A) \land (x \in X_a)] \land \varphi(x,y) \quad )$.

Now we need a rule for quantifiers :

> $\exists x P(x) \land Q \leftrightarrow \exists x (P(x) \land Q), \quad$ provided that $x$ is **not** *free* in $Q$.

In our formula above, $i$ is not *free* in $\varphi(x,y)$; thus we apply the rule to get :

$(\exists x) (\exists a) ( [(a \in A) \land (x \in X_a)] \land \varphi(x,y) )$.

Now we need a second rule for quantifiers :

> $\exists x \exists y P(x,y) \leftrightarrow \exists y \exists x P(x,y)$.

Applying it we have :

$(\exists a) (\exists x) ( [(a \in A) \land (x \in X_a)] \land \varphi(x,y) )$.

An this is (again "omitting" the index-set) :

> > $(\exists a) (\exists x) [(x \in X_a) \land f(x)=y]$

that, with a little "sloppiness", we write it as :

$∃a ∃x \in X_a (f(x)=y)$.

An then we can try to go on ...

Recalling that a *function* in set theory is a set of ordered couples, we have that $f(x)=y$ is :

$(x,y) \in f$

where in turn $f \subseteq X_a \times f[X_a]$.

Thus : $x \in X_a$ and $y \in f[X_a]$.

In conclusion, from : $∃a ∃x \in X_a (f(x)=y)$

we have that :

> $\exists a (y \in f[X_a])$.

*The last step is easy ... and I hope it can help.*

Comment: I feel that is an actual answer, because it hints that what the OP is trying to accomplish is not doable in this context, it lacks background, which you gave.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "concrete," but the following is correct.

$y \in f[\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha]$ if and only if there exists $x \in \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ such that $f(x) = y$. This happens if and only if there exists an $\alpha$ such that $x \in X_\alpha$ and $f(x) = y$, which in turn means that there is an $\alpha$ such that $y \in f[X_\alpha]$. But that means $y \in \bigcup_\alpha f[X_\alpha]$.

Given the number of things you've said above you don't like, this may or may not be anything like what you're looking for.

Edit: In the vague hope that you might like something more formal (and don't mind chaining "iff" signs in a manner that some mathematicians consider abusive), I offer the following.

\begin{align*}
y \in f\Big[\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha\Big] &\iff 
\exists x \in \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha \ \big(f(x) = y\big)\\
&\iff \exists \alpha\ \exists x \in X_\alpha \big(f(x) = y\big)\\
&\iff \exists \alpha\ \big(y \in f[X_\alpha]\big) \\
&\iff y \in \bigcup_\alpha f[X_\alpha].
\end{align*}

Comment: By don't like I mean "if I couldn't see that the thing I was trying to prove was right, I'd have no confidence that I had proved it" quite often with the more "intuitive" proofs I would end up proving something that wasn't true because I imagined a special case or something. So I try and at least have the ability to be overly demanding on the rigor I want in a proof.

Comment: But yeah, I got what you're saying, that is my 2 line proof which I start at the bottom, which I agree with. I'm dragging myself though the rigor of the top part of the question intentionally. I ought to be able to be that rigorous.

Comment: It may be that I've become less rigorous since I learned set algebra, but sometimes, there just isn't much more to do. Is Git Gud's answer to your liking?

Comment: I want to say yes for fear of seeming ungrateful, I was really hoping to work out which way the two exists went and proceed using first order logic. As I said I have "proved" it, in the way you wrote it, relying on intuitive parts like $y\in f(\cup_aX_a)\implies f^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset \cup_aX_a$ which I understand, I just (evidently) can't write using the same rigor I apply to analysis say.

Comment: I mean, that is the definition of inverse image, though, is it not?

Comment: Superb, thanks! One quick question, why did you choose to go $\exists\alpha\exists x$ why not, $\exists x\exists\alpha$ this is actually why I posted the question.

Comment: @AlecTeal Quantifiers of the same kind commute. Why is this? It comes from formal systems. In regular mathematics this is simply assumed. Without more background, it's not possible to justify this commutativity.

Comment: @GitGud seriously your comments are so annoying! For like the 9th time "where can I find out more about whatever that is" - even "what would I search for?" would be great, a subject name! A Book! Something I could search for! Anything! Stop teasing me!

Comment: @GitGud you've just shaken my idea that "variables that exist are some function of the things specified before them" I thought $\forall a\exists b\exists c$ meant c was something based off a and b, don't demolish that and leave me with nothing ;-)

Comment: @AlecTeal Any Mathematical Logic book. For instance Enderton's *A mathematical introduction to logic*.

Comment: @GitGud thank you, I'm off to the library. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't make a choice. An element is in a union precisely if it's in one of the sets being united, so this is just a formal recasting of the definition. The string "$\exists x \in X_\alpha\ \exists \alpha$" doesn't actually make much sense, so I guess that's why I didn't use it.

Comment: @AlecTeal Things can be formalized in the way you described, but they can also be formalized in different ways in which that idea is nothing more than intuition.

Comment: @jdc I justified the other order by thinking "I want to bold on a $\forall x\in\cup_aX_a\exists b:x\in X_b$, I had x first, so wanted to go given an x, I can find you a b, thinking b was a function of x. Equally thought I can find you one that goes the other way, even if it is computationally less efficient. But that doesn't matter in these statements.

Comment: Hey just to let you know I'm holding back on the tick until I find some books and what not, but I really am grateful. I hope you don't think I am not.

Comment: Also $\iff$ and $\implies$ got muddled up.... love it though, this is actually my chosen one.

Answer (score 2):

Using slightly different notations which I find more convenient, the statement to be proved is
$$
\tag{0} f[\langle \cup a :: X_a \rangle] \;=\; \langle \cup a ::  f[X_a] \rangle
$$
where the definitions are
\begin{align}
\tag{1} & y \in f[X] \;\equiv\; \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in X \rangle \\
\tag{2} & z \in \langle \cup a :: V(a) \rangle \;\equiv\; \langle \exists a :: z \in V(a) \rangle \\
\end{align}

For me, the simplest way to prove $(0)$ is to go to the element level using these definitions, and use the laws of logic: investigate which elements are part of the left hand side, and then transform into the right hand side.

---

In other words, for any $\;y\;$ we calculate as follows:

\begin{align}
& y \in f[\langle \cup a :: X_a \rangle] \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition (1) for $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in \langle \cup a :: X_a \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition (2) for $\;\langle \cup \ldots \rangle\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : \langle \exists a :: x \in  X_a \rangle \rangle \\
(*) \;\;\; \equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: exchange $\;\exists\;$ quantifications"} \\
& \langle \exists a :: \langle \exists x : f(x) = y : x \in  X_a \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition (1) for $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists a :: y \in f[X_a] \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition (2) for $\;\langle \cup \ldots \rangle\;$"} \\
& y \in \langle \cup a :: f[X_a] \rangle \\
\end{align}

which proves $(0)$ by set extensionality.

---

This proof clearly shows that the key step $(*)$ is that two nested $\;\exists\;$ quantifications (or two nested unions) may be exchanged.